# case statement efficiency in c

Tags: c, performance, switch-statement

I have a large switch statement, with about 250 cases, in Visual C:

```
#define BOP -42
#define COP -823
#define MOP -5759

int getScarFieldValue(int id, int ivIndex, int rayIndex, int scarIndex, int reamIndex)
{
    int returnValue = INT_MAX;  
    switch (id)
    {       
        case BOP      : returnValue  = Scar[ivIndex][rayIndex].bop[scarIndex][reamIndex];    break;
        case COP        : returnValue  = Scar[ivIndex][rayIndex].cop[scarIndex][reamIndex];       break;
        case MOP         : returnValue  = Scar[ivIndex][rayIndex].mop[scarIndex][reamIndex];     break;
        .....
        default:  return(INT_MAX);
     }
}
```

The #defines, you will notice, have a huge range, from -1 to -10,000.  The thing is dog slow, and I'm wondering if spending several hours redefining these 250 defines to a narrower (or even consecutive) range could speed things up.  I always thought the compiler would treat the case values in a way that made their numeric value irrelevant, but I have not been able to find any discussion to validate/invalidate that assumption.

Comment: If the program is slow and you're sure this function is the root of the problem, the problem is likely cache misses when you access memory rather than the switch statement.

Comment: I'm sure cache misses are also an issue.  Not much to do there, however: the app uses > 80gb ram, but the L1/L2/L3 caches max out at around 32MB.  (The wkstation is  dual 64-bit quad-core, with 12 physical/24 logical cores.)

Comment: Are the define values completely arbitrary?   If ID were defined as an enum, the compiler could automatically optimize this for you quite a bit.   And... did you say the program used *80GB* of memory ???

Comment: Yes the defines are completely arbitrary.  Actually, the wkstation has 192GB of memory.  The app usually uses only 80GB, but sometimes the data sets get large, and the app will use 184GB.

Comment: Can we see the complete list of values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disassemble the compiled code and see what the compiler does. I've looked at the output from several different compilers and large switch statements were always compiled into binary decision trees or jump tables. Jump tables are the most optimal thing you can get and they are more likely to be generated by the compiler if the values you're switching on are in a narrow range. It also helps have a default statement on some compilers (but not necessary on others).

This is one situation where disassembling is your only good option, the details of code generation on this level are rarely well documented.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use **hash table**, so you can search hash table instead of "`switch case`".

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the assembly output for the code, you will probably notice that your `switch` statement is being compiled into code that resembles cascading `if` statements:

```
if (id == BOP) ...
else if (id == COP) ...
else if (id == MOP) ...
...
else ...
```

Because of this, a simple tip to speed up the `switch` statement is to move the most commonly hit cases near the top.

If the case values are sorted, then the compiler may be able to generate a binary decision tree, reducing the complexity from linear to logarithmic.

At a high enough optimization level on a compiler that supports it, the compiler may be able to generate a computed `goto` style code. For non-consecutive values, the offset to jump to would be stored in a hash table, and a perfect hash function is generated for the case values. For consecutive values, there is no need for a hash function, as a simple indexed array can be used to store the jump offsets. You would have to check the assembler output for the optimized code to see if your compiler supports this functionality.

Otherwise, it may be better to create your own hash on the case value, and instead of using `switch`, you would do your own hash table lookup to find the right matrix to use, and then acquire your value.

Comment: Are you sure VC doesn't generate a binary tree? I haven't done any experiment but O(N) complexity seems easy to avoid.

Comment: It could generate a binary tree if it reordered the cases for you into a sorted order. I don't know if it does or not.

Comment: I've read the generated output from several compilers and all of them generate binary decision trees or jump tables for large switch statements. It should be quite easy to verify.

Comment: I have updated the answer to reflect that a binary decision tree is possible too. Thanks.

Comment: I like to learn from my mistakes, so reasons for the downvote would be appreciated.

Comment: @Art, I believe it is not always possible to generate a binary decision tree, if the case labels are not in consecutive order, and the order is necessary for "fallthrough" actions to work correctly. I do believe a compiler could reorder the case statements in an attempt to generate a binary decision tree, but it may give up if the fallthrough cases are too complicated for it to sort out.

Comment: Jump tables are also quite common.

Comment: @meaning-matters: I called it "computed goto", but it is the same idea.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution:
Break switch case into multiple parts.

```
if(id<=50)
{
    switch(id)
    {
      //All cases between 0 to 50
    }
}
else if (id>50 && id<=100)
{
    switch(id)
    {
      //All cases between 51 to 100
}
//and so on
```

the choice of range is yours. And dont create many ranges. This will ensure a code faster than your current code.
Alternatively you can use function pointers and write functions containing the statements that are to be executed in the case.
I would have preferred this method.

```
typedef struct
{
    void(*Cur_FunctnPtr)();     
}CMDS_Functn;

void (*Cur_Func)();
CMDS_Functn FunctionArray[66] = {
                    /*00-07*/    (*Func1),(*Func2),(*Func3),...
                    /*08-0F*/       

                    /*40-47*/       };

void my_func()
{
...  //what ever code
    Cur_Func = FunctionArray[id].Cur_FunctnPtr; //Load current Function Pointer
        (*Cur_Func)();
... // what ever code
}
```

Comment: Breaking the switch-case ensures that only if the **id** value falls between the specified range then that switch-case will be tested for the exact value, not executing the other checks, thus saving some amount of time.

Comment: Before doing this, it would be good to inspect the compiler's output (e.g. step through instructions with the debugger) to be sure it didn't do the same thing automatically.

Comment: The function pointer array is a array (look-up table) having the addresses of the functions. when you call any function using the function pointer, the address is loaded and the execution jumps to that part directly and starts the execution. this is way faster than the traditional if-else or switch-case, for the number of cases that you have specified.

Comment: It would make sense to mention the alternative in the answer. I just got confused and thought you were someone else writing a comment.

Comment: @Potatoswatter is right. Some compiler optimization do this. But if you implement this code style, the compiler is forced to generate a faster code, irrespective of the optimization level.

Comment: It's not an optimization at all. It's just a way of generating branches to link the basic blocks it inevitably has. Different optimization levels could alter switch generation, but probably won't. There's no guarantee that the manual choice of branch conditions will be better than the automatic selection. Manual specification may adversely affect PGO.

Answer (score 1):

Read the code to figure out what the `switch` compiles to.

If you have a hash table implementation handy, you could try using that, but it will of course require you to extract all the "action" code into something you can jump to from a hashtable lookup result.

If using GCC, I would do a quick test combining [GCC's computed goto](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html#Labels-as-Values) with a simple sorted array so you can use good old [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). The latter will cut the number of worst-case comparisons done by your code from 250/2 to log<sub>2</sub>(250), i.e. around 8.

This will require a look-up table declared at compile-time (and perhaps sorted, once, at run-time), which probably is better in terms of memory overhead than most hashtables will manage.

Comment: If using GCC the compiler does this for you in large switch statements, there's no reason to uglify the code with computed gotos (also, computed gotos scare the compiler enough to prevent many other optimizations in the function).

Answer (score 0):

If you know the characteristics of the distribution of likely id values, test for them in  most-likely to least-likely order in your case statement.

If this gets called frequently, you might want to consider storing the choices in a Dictionary:  they get resolved without serial comparisons, and thus might save a lot of time if there are really 10,002 choices.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the range of the IDs is not consecutive. No compiler can do better on that than with a cascade of conditions of logarithmic depth, here about 8.

A method to heal this would be to use an `enum` that gets you the IDs consecutive and the compiler then can use a jump table to speed things up. To really know if that'd work you'd have to check the rest of your application to see if it supports changing the values.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler will only optimise using techniques it's aware of, and if none of those techniques work then you'll get something terrible.

You could either implement something yourself, or you could try to give the compiler some clues.  In the latter case you have a fair chance of the compiler "getting it" and then optimising the solution further than your own implementation can -- and the compiler can avoid C syntax limitations which would constrain your own solution.

As for solutions; obviously the best is to renumber them to be consecutive.

Another approach is to take your 250 values and search for a *perfect* hash function to reduce them to an 8-bit quantity.

```
#define PERFECT_HASH(x) ((x) & 0xff) /* some clever function of x */

switch (PERFECT_HASH(id))
{       
case PERFECT_HASH(BOP): returnValue  = Scar[ivIndex][rayIndex].bop[scarIndex][reamIndex];    break;
case PERFECT_HASH(COP): returnValue  = Scar[ivIndex][rayIndex].cop[scarIndex][reamIndex];       break;
case PERFECT_HASH(MOP): returnValue  = Scar[ivIndex][rayIndex].mop[scarIndex][reamIndex];     break;
.....
default:  return(INT_MAX);
}
```

But, having cut and paste that code, it looks like you're using a switch statement to convert `id` into what is effectively a pointer value to different pieces of the data structure.  If all the cases contain a single read of the same kind of pointer then you definitely don't want to use a switch for that.  You need to look at the shape of your data and find a way to compute that pointer more directly.  Or switch simply on the type and compute the address separately.